# how to show one artical from a category and rest of articals as an archive in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress, I have created several posts with category newsletter type.
Now It renders all the newsletter on the newsletter tab. What I want to do is to show the latest newsletter only and rest of the newsletters as archive list.

What I can do is , I have decided to create a new template page for this and render all newsletters.
But how to limit to latest newsletter and show rest of them as archive list?

following method will give archieved list but I want to select only articales related to catergory newsletter.

```
wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'daily', 'limit' => 15 ) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a function I've used before but looks like it should do what you need: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts

Just change the posts_per_page to 1.

(EDIT: And also change the category to the ID of your newsletter category)